# How do i click an element in a div and get the text content of that element which is derived from an object in array which was looped to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I had an array of object which i looped out to the DOM into a div container. With the class employers-container.
I want to click on each element on the DOM and get the text content of each element. How do i do that using javascript?

Here is the JavaScript code i used to loop it out to the DOM.

````
const employersContainer = document.querySelector('.employer-container');

const arrOfObj = [
     {
      name: 'Joe',
      occupation: 'Footballer' 
     },
     {
      name: 'Alex',
      occupation: 'Doctor' 
     },
     {
      name: 'Sam',
      occupation: 'Superhero' 
     },
];


            const employersMapToDOM = () => {
            var content = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < arrOfObj.length;i++) {
            content +=`
                    <div class="employee-case" onclick="getThisTagValue()">
                        <div>
                            <h4 class="person">${arrOfObj[i].name}</h4>
                            <p class="work">${arrOfObj[i].occupation}</p>
                        </div>                   
                 </div>`;
            }


            employersContainer.innerHTML = content;
      
            }

            employersMapToDOM();


            const getThisTagValue = () => {
                    const employeeCase = document.querySelector('.employee-case');

                    console.log(employeeCase.textContent);
            }

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop, you do `arrOfObj.name`. But `arrOfObj` is an Array, and does not have a `name` property. You need to extract the `person` first, then use its properties:

```js
const employersContainer = document.querySelector('.employer-container');

const arrOfObj = [{name: 'Joe',  occupation: 'Footballer'},
                  {name: 'Alex', occupation: 'Doctor'    },
                  {name: 'Sam',  occupation: 'Superhero' }];


const employersMapToDOM = () => {
  var content = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < arrOfObj.length; i++) {
    var person = arrOfObj[i];
    content += `<div class="employee-case" onclick="getThisTagValue(this)">
                  <div>
                    <h4 class="person">${person.name}</h4>
                    <p class="work">${person.occupation}</p>
                  </div>                   
                </div>`;
  }
  employersContainer.innerHTML = content;
}

employersMapToDOM();

const getThisTagValue = (employeeCase) => {
  let str = employeeCase.textContent;
  // If you want to remove line breaks and extra spaces:
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<div class="employer-container"></div>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. But to get to the very answer, i want to click the employee-case of each persons and their works displayed. That is if i click the employee-case of Joe who's work is a footballer it should return the text content "Joe Footballer"; But i every time i do this and i click all of them, they all return "joe footballer".

Comment: I'm clicking in Alex or Sam and I'm still getting "joe footballer (i used the "onclick()"  method on the employee case to do it). Now that's my problem. I want to click each of them and when i do, let it return their own value. (If i click Alex, i get Alex's text content. If i click Sam, i get Sam's content and so on)

Comment: Please update your question with your current code, including the part where you setup the click event listener, it will be easier

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. Note that I added `this` in `onclick="getThisTagValue(this)"` so that we know which div was clicked

Comment: Thanks Blex. You have saved the day, i thought of trying out "this" 2days ago. But i guess i skipped my mind. Thank you sooo much. I will do more research on how to use "this"